# How to fetch Arraylist data with Retrofit?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, gson, retrofit2

Currently I'm trying to create a nested RecyclerView and use Retrofit to fetch my data. When I run the code, no error shown on log cat but the come out doesn't appear like how I expect it to be. May someone please help me to find why its appear empty? where should I improve my code?

Here is what I've try so far

API interface

```
package com.example.recycledviewpoolexample.API;

import com.example.recycledviewpoolexample.Item;
import com.example.recycledviewpoolexample.SubItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public interface API {
    @GET("job")
    Call<ArrayList<Item>> getItem();

    @GET("job")
    Call<ArrayList<SubItem>> getSubItem();
}
```

Retrofit

```
package com.example.recycledviewpoolexample.API;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class RetrofitClient {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.1.15/api/";
    private static RetrofitClient mInstance;
    private final Retrofit retrofit;

    private RetrofitClient() {

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
    }

    public static synchronized RetrofitClient getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new RetrofitClient();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public API getAPI() {
        return retrofit.create(API.class);
    }
}
```

item (model)

```
package com.example.recycledviewpoolexample;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;

public class Item {

    @SerializedName("customer_name")

    private String customer_name;

    private List<SubItem> subItemList;

    public Item(String customer_name, List<SubItem> subItemList) {
        this.customer_name = customer_name;
        this.subItemList = subItemList;
    }

    public String getCustomer_name() {
        return customer_name;
    }

    public void setCustomer_name(String customer_name) {
        this.customer_name = customer_name;
    }

    public List<SubItem> getSubItemList() {
        return subItemList;
    }

    public void setSubItemList(List<SubItem> subItemList) {
        this.subItemList = subItemList;
    }
}
```

ItemAdapter

```
package com.example.recycledviewpoolexample;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {

    public RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool viewPool = new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool();

    List<Item> itemList;

    public ItemAdapter(List<Item> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new ItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder, int i) {
        Item item = itemList.get(i);
        itemViewHolder.customer_name.setText(item.getCustomer_name());

        // Create layout manager with initial prefetch item count
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(
                itemViewHolder.rvSubItem.getContext(),
                LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,
                false
        );
        layoutManager.setInitialPrefetchItemCount(item.getSubItemList().size());

        // Create sub item view adapter
        SubItemAdapter subItemAdapter = new SubItemAdapter(item.getSubItemList());

        itemViewHolder.rvSubItem.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        itemViewHolder.rvSubItem.setAdapter(subItemAdapter);
        itemViewHolder.rvSubItem.setRecycledViewPool(viewPool);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }

    class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

       TextView customer_name;
       RecyclerView rvSubItem;

        ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            customer_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.todocustomer_name);
            rvSubItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_sub_item);
        }
    }
}
```

SubItem (model)

```
package com.example.recycledviewpoolexample;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class SubItem {

    private int subItemImage;
    private String subItemTitle;
    private String subItemDesc;

    @SerializedName("job_priority")
    private String job_priority;

    @SerializedName("job_order_number")
    private String job_order_number;

    @SerializedName("job_description")
    private String job_description;

    @SerializedName("machine_name")
    private String machine_name;

    @SerializedName("machine_type")
    private String machine_type;

    @SerializedName("serial_number")
    private String serial_number;

    @SerializedName("reason")
    private String reason;

    public SubItem(String subItemTitle,
                   String subItemDesc,
                   String job_priority,
                   String job_order_number,
                   String job_description,
                   String machine_name,
                   String machine_type,
                   String serial_number,
                   String reason)

    {
        this.subItemTitle = subItemTitle;
        this.subItemDesc = subItemDesc;
        this.job_priority = job_priority;
        this.job_order_number = job_order_number;
        this.job_description = job_description;
        this.machine_name = machine_name;
        this.machine_type = machine_type;
        this.serial_number = serial_number;
        this.reason = reason;
    }

    public int getSubItemImage() {
        return subItemImage;
    }

    public void setSubItemImage(int subItemImage) {
        this.subItemImage = subItemImage;
    }

    public String getSubItemDesc() {
        return subItemDesc;
    }

    public void setSubItemDesc(String subItemDesc) {
        this.subItemDesc = subItemDesc;
    }

    public String getJob_priority() {
        return job_priority;
    }

    public void setJob_priority(String job_priority) {
        this.job_priority = job_priority;
    }

    public String getJob_order_number() {
        return job_order_number;
    }

    public void setJob_order_number(String job_order_number) {
        this.job_order_number = job_order_number;
    }

    public String getJob_description() {
        return job_description;
    }

    public void setJob_description(String job_description) {
        this.job_description = job_description;
    }

    public String getMachine_name() {
        return machine_name;
    }

    public void setMachine_name(String machine_name) {
        this.machine_name = machine_name;
    }

    public String getMachine_type() {
        return machine_type;
    }

    public void setMachine_type(String machine_type) {
        this.machine_type = machine_type;
    }

    public String getSerial_number() {
        return serial_number;
    }

    public void setSerial_number(String serial_number) {
        this.serial_number = serial_number;
    }

    public String getReason() {
        return reason;
    }

    public void setReason(String reason) {
        this.reason = reason;
    }
}
```

SubItemAdapter

```
package com.example.recycledviewpoolexample;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class SubItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SubItemAdapter.SubItemViewHolder> {

    List<SubItem> subItemList;

    public SubItemAdapter(List<SubItem> subItemList) {
        this.subItemList = subItemList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SubItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_sub_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new SubItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SubItemViewHolder subItemViewHolder, int i) {
        SubItem subItem = subItemList.get(i);
        subItemViewHolder.job_order_number.setText(subItem.getJob_order_number());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return subItemList.size();
    }

    class SubItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView job_order_number;
        TextView job_priority;
        TextView job_description;
        TextView machine_name;
        TextView machine_type;
        TextView serial_number;
        TextView reason;

        SubItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            job_order_number = itemView.findViewById(R.id.todojob_order_number);
            job_priority = itemView.findViewById(R.id.todojob_priority);
            job_description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.todojob_description);
            machine_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.todomachine_name);
            machine_type = itemView.findViewById(R.id.todomachine_type);
            serial_number = itemView.findViewById(R.id.todoserialnumber);
            reason = itemView.findViewById(R.id.reason);
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
package com.example.recycledviewpoolexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.recycledviewpoolexample.API.RetrofitClient;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
    ArrayList<SubItem> subItemList = new ArrayList<SubItem>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RecyclerView rvItem = findViewById(R.id.rv_item);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
        ItemAdapter itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(buildItemList());
        rvItem.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
        rvItem.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    }

    private ArrayList<Item> buildItemList() {

        Call<ArrayList<Item>> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getAPI().getItem();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Item>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Item>> call, Response<ArrayList<Item>> response) {
                itemList.addAll(response.body());
                for (int i=0; i<itemList.size(); i++) {
                    Item item = new Item("Item "+i, buildSubItemList());
                    itemList.add(item);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Item>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        return itemList;
    }

    private ArrayList<SubItem> buildSubItemList() {

        Call<ArrayList<SubItem>> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getAPI().getSubItem();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<SubItem>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<SubItem>> call, Response<ArrayList<SubItem>> response) {
                subItemList.addAll(response.body());
                for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
                    SubItem subItem = new SubItem("Sub Item "+i, "Description "+i,
                            "Description "+i,
                            "Description "+i,
                            "Description "+i,
                            "Description "+i,
                            "Description "+i,
                            "Description "+i,
                            "Description "+i);
                    subItemList.add(subItem);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<SubItem>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        return subItemList;
    }
}
```

This is how I expect it to be

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZMDK.png)

But currently it appear empty like this

[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShS9O.png)

Comment: I think you forgot to pass new data to the adapter call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` but I am not sure how it wuld react when you fetch data on every element. But that method refreshes the view after you add the data.

Comment: You are calling API in `buildItemList` and `buildSubItemList` method which is async operation what's happening is you are returning list immediately which is empty but api response is coming after sometime you should notify adatper as mentioned for structural change.

Comment: @LukášAnda thank you for your opinion. I try to search about `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` since yesterday but still have no idea where to put in my code. nevermind I'll try again.

Comment: @pintu236 thank you for replying. I'll try to restructure my code again